# my photo is under Everything

Tags: html, css

When I Move the scroll my photo go to under everything:

the code is :

```
<a target="_blank" href="reg.php" >
<img src="/L_c_f_3.gif" width="110px" alt="ribbon" style="position:fixed;bottom: 8px;right: 16px;"></a>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bring an image in front of text HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418808/how-can-i-bring-an-image-in-front-of-text-html)!

Answer (score 0):

```
position: relative; z-index: 999;
```

Comment: `999` is  overkill, I would say it's bad habit

Comment: Yeah I know. But if he asks this kind of question here, I can see he has no real knowledge of css therefore that should do the trick for him

Comment: teaching him bad practices will not allow him to ask better questions in the future, no one of us started as an expert. Sure, he deserves the downvotes, but if you decide to answer, than you should show a bit more effort to at least give a high quality answer, preferably with a little bit of explanation.